# "It's worth it". What does each "it" indicate?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

I've heard it tons of times from people, media, the internet and everywhere, but I guess I was too afraid to ask *what does the first and second **it** indicate*? I assume both are not indicating the same thing because it's plain redundant.

Bonus question: I remember my English teacher said never use the same pronoun (like **it**) twice in a sentence, especially they are supposed to indicate different things. Can I safely assume "It's worth it" is an exception from this?

Comment: *"my English teacher said never use the same pronoun (like it) twice in a sentence"* - this is not a strict rule.  Your writing might be clearer if you don't use the same pronoun twice, but it isn't a rule and there are plenty of times when people do it.  (Like I just did in that sentence!)

Comment: @stangdon Clever! 

Answer (score 2):

It's worth it, usually means, it's worth the effort/time/money to acquire "it".

A colloquialism that you wouldn't find in formal writing.